# Does WireMock playback when in record?

Tags: web-services, testing, wiremock

I've been playing around with WireMock (Standalone) recently and think it's great. Today I noticed behaviour which, as far as I can see, suggests that WireMock plays back already-saved responses, when in record mode.

I think I could be mistaken because this is pretty important to know, yet I can't see it in the documentation, except for this:

> [Note](http://wiremock.org/record-playback.html)
>
> The recorder will ignore any request matching one it has already
>   captured.

It's not clear if that means :

1. The request will be routed to the 3rd party service and a live response will be returned. Or,
2. The saved response will be returned and the 3rd party service will not be bothered in that case.

I hope it is the latter. It basically means that in small apps, playback may never be required.

Can anyone confirm this for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in record mode (assuming you've also configured proxying) no stubs will be created in memory and served, they'll only be saved to disk. This means WireMock will only start serving those stubs after you've restarted it.

The "...recorder will ignore..." statement means that it won't attempt to record the same stub twice - if it sees what it considers to be an identical request to one previously seen in the recording session, it'll still pass it through the proxy but won't (re) record the response.

Comment: Thanks Tom. That answers my question. I now have to figure out why I appeared to be receiving saved responses in record mode. Nice to be able to rule this out.